# Cauchy differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I'm trying to resolve this cauchy problem:

$ y'=2y+1$ such as $y(0)=1$

the general integral for the differential equation is $\frac{1}{2}(e^{2x+2c_1}-1)$

for $y(0)=1$ :

$y(0)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{2c_1}-1)=1$

my doubt is about the fact that i don't know how to "get down" that $c_1$ and i can't resolve the problem, can you help me with this one?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: it should be correct! thank you for you help, i'll try to do as you said

Comment: If the solution you showed is correct then you simply have to solve: $\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{2C_{1}}-1\right) = 1$ for $C_{1}$. You should get $C_{1} = \frac{ln(3)}{2}$. Sorry for the confusion in the first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{2x+2c_1}-1)$$
$$t(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{2x}e^{2c_1}-1)$$
$e^{2c_1}$ is just a constant 
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{2}(Ke^{2x}-1) $$
And therefore
$$y(0)=1 \implies K=3 \implies y(x)=\frac{1}{2}(3e^{2x}-1)$$

edit

$$y(0)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{2c_1}-1)=1$$
$$\implies e^{2c_1}=3 $$
so substitute to $e^{2c_1}$ its value 3...you don't need to evaluate $c_1$

$$\frac{1}{2}(e^{2c_1}-1)=1$$
$$(e^{2c_1}-1)=2$$
$$e^{2c_1}=3$$
$$e^{2c_1}=e^{\ln 3}$$
$$(c_1= \frac {\ln 3}2)$$

Comment: how do I assign that 3 though?, why is $c_1=\frac{ln(3)}{2} $ ?

Comment: ok I derive $e^2x$ right?

Comment: for the initial condition remeber that $y(0)=1$ means that when $x=0$ then $y=1$ @GabrieleSortino so yes thats the formula you posted with ln

Comment: @GabrieleSortino I added some lines...and yes $c_1= \ln (3 )/2$

Comment: I GOT IT, i'm pretty tired and even the most simple thing was shady and confusing. Thank you for your help

Comment: just can you explain why $c_1=\frac{ln(3)}{2}$ ?

Comment: thats great you got it now ...yw @GabrieleSortino...

Comment: @GabrieleSortino I added some lines hope it's more clear...

Comment: You are the man, thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have $e^{2x+2x_1}=e^{2c_1}\,e^{2x}$. And, whenever you have a "function of a constant", you can think of it as a constant. So your solution is 
$$
y(x)=\frac12\,(d\,e^{2x}-1). 
$$
Then 
$$
1=y(0)=\frac{d-1}2,
$$
so $d=3$.